# Ionic - ion-item text is not vertically centered when ion-icon is bigger

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a list of ion-items with an icon followed by text. When the icon size is smaller as seen on the image below, the text seems to vertically align itself to the center of the `ion-item`. But when the icon is bigger, the alignment is a bit off.

[image]

This is all I've added:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-icon> 
  Recent
</ion-item>
```

And the CSS:

```
.icon {
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #ffC977;
}
```

How can I fix this. I tried using `vertical-align`, `align-item` and `align-self`. None of them worked.

Comment: Enclosing the text within `<ion-label>` tags will cause it to be vertically centred. In this case, if the text was changed to `<ion-label>Recent</ion-label>`, it would be vertically centred.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this. Add a `<span>` element to the text, `vertical-align` only works with elements inline side by side :

**CSS**

```
.icon {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #ffC977;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.text{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-icon> 
  <span class="text">Recent</span>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This works! I didn't know about the elements having to be inline to use vertical-align. Thanks!

Comment: This is useful especially when not being used in ion-item..thanks!

Comment: **display: flex;** for the parent
**margin: auto;** for label will help without any size hardcoding

Answer (score 9):

Actually Ionic does that to you. But you need to inform where the elements will be with `item-start`, `item-end`, etc.

Just set your code like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-icon item-start name="ion-ios-clock-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon> 
    Recent
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Shortest & Accurate. Thank you for the help. I don't think we should play with raw css for this minor change which is already provided with a solution from Ionic Team. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="font-size: 18px;vertical-align: middle !important;">
    <ion-icon name="location" class="location-icon"></ion-icon>
  </span>
  <span style="height:80px !important;">
    <b style="font-size: 18px;vertical-align: middle !important;">Port Louis, MU</b>
  </span>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Using **padding-vertical** css utilities can bring the same result.
A list of css utilities for Ionic can be seen here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-25>
                <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-icon> 
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-75 padding-vertical>
                Recent
            </ion-col>              
        </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score -3):

Please update your following CSS Class. Also you can move your text to a label tag and give the vertical-align middle for the label tag as well.

**CSS**

```
.icon {
     font-size: 35px;
     color: #ffC977; 
     vertical-align: middle;
    }

    label{ 
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-icon> 
  <label>Recent</label>
</ion-item>
```