# Objects in my category page are not vertically aligned

Tags: css, sass, vertical-alignment

I have a page where I list the product categories. This page lists category visuals and category names. But category image and category name do not align vertically. I want to align these two objects vertically for each screen size. Thank you.
[My categories page picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB8hz.png)
Codes :

```html
 <ion-item [hidden]="!anaListeGoster" *ngFor="let list of anaKategoriListesi" (tap)="kodYakala(list.OZELKOD, list.ACIKLAMA, list.ID)">
    <div class="resimKutusu">
      <img class="kategoriResimleri" [src]="'xx.com.xx.com'+list.OZELKOD+'.jpg'">
    </div>
    <span class="aciklamaYazisi"> {{ aciklamaKisalt(list.ACIKLAMA) }} </span>
    <ion-icon class="devamEtIcon" name="ios-arrow-forward" item-end></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

```css
.resimKutusu{
    float: left;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;

    
}
.kategoriResimleri{
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: none;
    height: 50px;
    
}
.aciklamaYazisi{
    font-size:16px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top : 5%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623280/ionic-ion-item-text-is-not-vertically-centered-when-ion-icon-is-bigger/35623396#35623396

Comment: Please provide one single snippet with the css and generated html so we can see it in action

Comment: @LuisP.A. I tried but I did not get a result

Comment: Can you build a html with a css, can be only one example in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
.resimKutusu {
    display: content;
    float: left;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```